# What does 'track' mean when creating a new branch in git?

Tags: git, aptana

I'm using Aptana and Git.  When I go to create a new branch, the following dialog box shows up.

[image]

I was wondering what that 'track' checkbox does, and when it's most appropriate to check it.

I understand the concept of tracking in git, but mostly with files.  I don't seem to understand how it applies to new branches being created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, `track` refers to git-checkout's and git-branch's `--track` option.

When a local branch is started off a remote-tracking branch, git sets up the branch so that `git pull` will appropriately merge from the remote-tracking branch.

From `man git-branch`:

> ```
> -t, --track
>     When creating a new branch, set up configuration to mark the
>     start-point branch as "upstream" from the new branch. This
>     configuration will tell git to show the relationship between the
>     two branches in git status and git branch -v. Furthermore, it
>     directs git pull without arguments to pull from the upstream when
>     the new branch is checked out.
> ```

Comment: Ah, okay.  So if I create a new branch off of master and track it.  I can continue working on my branch while pulling changes made in master while I was working on my branch?  Let me know if I understood right, thanks!

Comment: However, both of these branches are local.  So when would the merge take place?

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct. The merge would take place at `git pull` in any case, even if the tracked branch is local.

Comment: @MarcoLeogrande - The sentence "When a local branch is started off a remote-tracking branch" is from the `git-branch` man page. Shouldn't it be phrased as this: "When a local branch is started off as a remote-tracking branch"?

Answer (score 11):

I still didn't understand the answer provided by *Marco*, even after reading through the comments. So I decided to look into it further myself and provide an answer in layman's terms...

---

**Local Branch:** Is a path that *branches off* from the master branch of the Git. The master branch is the main path where changes are finally committed. The branch is local and is not linked to a remote one.

**Remote Branch:** Same as a 'local branch', but is situated on the remote Git. The branch is remote and is not linked to a local one.

**Remote-tracking Branch:**

- They are used to link what you are working on locally, with that on the remote.
- They know which remote branch to grab changes from when `git pull` or `git fetch` is executed. Typing `git status` will state how many commits ahead you are of the remote branch.

**The punchline...**

Using `--track` will create the branch and then automatically 'pull' from the chosen branch. So in this case (referring to the image in the question), a new branch will be created **locally** with the name 'feat/password-confirmation' and it will compare with the remote branch named 'master' (the main path on the remote)

I thought you said the master branch was local? The main path locally and on the remote are both called 'master', but only interact with `git push` or `git pull`.

You do not need to tick the 'Track' checkbox if you do not need to track the remote Git.

---

Hope that helps.

[Source](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/09/remote-tracking-branches.html)